# warning: '-managedObjectContext' not found in protocol(s)

Tags: iphone

I'm using the following code to reach the MOC in my second view controller

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }
```

I got the above error and I don't know how to get rid of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

When doing this, the compiler/Xcode knows your `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` is an instance of `YourAppDelegate`, so it knows it has the `managedObjectContext` property.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but in this case I had to import my YourAppDelegate.h in my second / child view controller!?!

Comment: Yes, indeed. For the compiler/Xcode to know about the `YourAppDelegate` class while compiling this file, it needs access to the header for that class: `YourAppDelegate.h`.

If this solved your problem, could you perhaps Accept and +1 my answer? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't forget to import your AppDelegate first!

Comment: @Mladjan; As described in the two comments before yours ;)

Comment: heheh, sorry Douwe, it was 4am in my city xD

Comment: You can also cast the sharedApplication instance to type (id), to avoid importing the custom AppDelegate. This is useful for example in library classes which you are using in multiple projects.